# Shopify: Hide a button that has the same attributes as a sibling button

Tags: php, html, css, frontend, shopify

In a Shopify collection page, I got two buttons with the same HTML to display products in two styles. I need to disable vertical display of the products. Could you please help me add the CSS to make it hidden? The button marked in the image below should be hidden.Link to the page is [here](https://5uwsjpaje6ps6xog-458195004.shopifypreview.com) Please any collection page to see these buttons.

[image]

Comment: Please read [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: use CSS `.filter__views .filter__view:nth-child(2) {display: none;}` to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this css code in your css file which is available on your page

your css file
assets/bold-options.css

css code:-

```
.filter__views .filter__view:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;}
```

this code will hide your button which marked in the image